# Running java from html

Tags: java, html, applet

I've set up webpage1 with the following code in it's index.html source:

```
<applet width='1' height='1' code='java.class' archive='java.jar'></applet>
```

So when you go to webpage1 it automatically runs the java file in the directory.

Now, I'm setting up webpage2 and want to have it set up so that when you press on a button/image/link/etc. it automatically runs the java stuff on webpage1 (without actually redirecting to webpage1)

How to do this?
Thanks in forward :)

Comment: Won't the attributes `width='1' height='1'` make the applet too small to see?

Answer (score 1):

> How to do this?

Write a browser that behaves like that.

Comment: so what you're saying is that is FF/IE/Chrome don't support this kind of a feature..?

Comment: Short answer, no.  Long answer, nope.  The web-app. needs to be redesigned.